# How do I change file/directory permission of a nfs mounted directory, so I access files as user?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, nfs, file-sharing

On a Ubuntu computer I mounted a directory from another computer using the following line in the `fstab`:

```
12.34.56.78:/space/Images /mnt/space/images nfs rsize=16384,wsize=16384,rw,auto,nolock 0 0
```

When working inside this mounted directory I only can work with superuser rights, and even the attempt to change them with

```
sudo chgrp -R linuxuser Images/
```

resulted in errors of the type:

```
chgrp: changing group of `file': Invalid argument
```

How can I mount the partition instead, so I can work in it as a normal user (without using `sudo` even for a `ls`)?

**Additional information:**

- On the server side I followed [this example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-12-04).
- The user and their IDs are different on server and client.

Comment: the change is server related I think, but I may mistaken

Comment: Do you have the same user on the server and the client? Do the two users have the same userID?

Comment: What exactly does `/etc/exports` say on the NFS server?